# how to submit a form using backbone and backbone.validation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, validation

I am using Backbone version 0.9.2,
jquery version 1.7.2 and
[Backbone.Validation v0.5.2](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation).

My html look like (1), the backbone.view (2) and the backbone.model (3).

It seems that my implementation does not work at all anymore.
When I click on submit button, it performs a POST request without making any form validation.

Any ideas why and how can I fix this problem?

Please see the comments in my code.

Thanks.

(1)

```
<form method="POST" class="form1">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="reason" class="control-label">Reason</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea id="reason" name="reason" required="required" /></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- other codes -->
</form>
```

(2)

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.model = new MyModel();

        this.model.bind('validated:invalid', function(model, attrs) {
            console.log('validated:invalid', model, attrs); // It does not work
        });
        this.model.bind('validated:valid', function(model) {
            console.log('validated:valid', model); // It does not work
        });
   },

    events: {
        'click [data-tid="submit"]': 'submitForm'
    },

    submitForm: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.model.set(data);
        this.model.save({
            success: function () {
        // some code
            }
        });
    }
```

(3)

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: 'someUrl',

    validation: {
        reason: {
            required: true,
            msg: 'Reason is required'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Backbone.Validation.bind(this) after you created the model in initialize.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can use form validation. I think you need to listen to the submit event.

Backbone works as they should.

```
 events: {      
   'submit': 'submit'
 }
```